# Determine foliation given by vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, foliations

While studying for an upcoming exam, I've found the following problem:

> Let $X = xz\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + yzxz\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $Y = (1 + z^2)xz\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ be vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Determine $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ maximal open set such that $X,Y$ define a foliation in $\mathcal{U}$ and describe such a foliation.

My attempt: I can define a distribution $D: \mathbb{R}^3 \to T_p\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$D(p) = D_p := \langle X, Y \rangle|_p (= \operatorname{Span}\{X, Y\}|_p).$$
Then, I can show that there is a maximal open set $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $D$ restricted to $\mathcal{U}$ is involutive (namely, $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{X}(D)$, for $\mathfrak{X}(D)$ vector fields of $D$). If $D$ is involutive then $D$ is integrable, by Frobenius's Theorem, and thus there is some foliation $\mathcal{F}$ such that $D = T\mathcal{F}$.

But I do not know how to proceed from there, i.e., I don't know how to explicitly determine the leaves of $\mathcal{F}$. Also, is this the way to go, or there is a better way to proceed?

Comment: Why do you want to determine the leaves of the foliation? The question just asks to determine $U$, which follows from Frobenius Theorem by what you have said. In general it is a hard thing to determine the leaves of an integrable distrubution since it is equivalent to solve some families of PDEs, which is a hard problem in full generality

Comment: @Didier, the question I've posted was incomplete. I've edited it. Thank you

Comment: Right, now it is a different problem! You can reduce the problem by noticing that if $x$ and $z$ are nonzero, then the distribution is spanned by $\partial_x + yz \partial_y$ and $\partial_z$. Solving the corresponding equations would be a lot easier.